# Kivy: Set image background and stretch through python

Tags: python, kivy

I've searched everywhere on how to simply set the background of a Kivy app to an image, stretched to fit the screen, using python - only caveat is that I can't easily use a kv file to do so without reworking the majority of the app. Anything I've found pertaining to this just results in no change in background or countless errors. Is there any way to easily do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `App` class, add methods:

```
def set_background(self, *args):
    self.root_window.bind(size=self.do_resize)
    with self.root_window.canvas.before:
        self.bg = Rectangle(source='someImage.png', pos=(0,0), size=(self.root_window.size))

def do_resize(self, *args):
    self.bg.size = self.root_window.size
```

Then, in your `build()` method add:

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.set_background, 0)
```